# Installation of browser-sync on MAC rejected by OS

Tags: node.js, npm, browser-sync

I Just installed node.js on my MAC and then tried to install *browser-sync* following the web instructions but got these errors but I don't know how to fix it. Could you help me solving it?

````
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.```
````

Comment: EACCES means insufficient permissions when creating the directory - as the trace implicitly tells you.. Check your permissions and set them acccordingly. See https://www.macinstruct.com/tutorials/how-to-set-file-permissions-on-a-mac/

Comment: @iLuvLogix, thanks for your help.

Comment: De nada! You could  self-answer your question, basically describing what you did  to solve your problem - future visitors might find it helpful in case they run into a similar issue.. ;)

Answer (score -1):

As [@iLuvLogix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9793532/iluvlogix) said [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70522768/installation-of-browser-sync-on-mac-rejected-by-os/70533264#comment124662953_70522768), it was a matter of giving r/w permissions. After granting permissions I ran into the same problem several times (each time I run the installation command I got a new error on a different folder), so after each try I had to set new permissions until finally I got it installed completely. Annoying but effective.